Fold emulator, views are repeated and copied when folding/unfolding
When I fold or unfold in the emulator, the views are copied on the previous views!
What is the reason for this and the Oncreate method is called twice, these views are on a fragment in an activity...
https://iili.io/dqBaAa2.png
I tried to delete the views after each change of screen status so that the new views are not copied on them, but it didn't work...
